# Python replace regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string in which there are some attributes that may be empty:

```
[attribute1=value1, attribute2=, attribute3=value3, attribute4=]
```

With python I need to sobstitute the empty values with the value 'None'. I know I can use the `string.replace('=,','=None,').replace('=]','=None]')` for the string but I'm wondering if there is a way to do it using a regex, maybe with the `?P<name>` option.

Comment: You should give it a try first. Try to write up a regex that will match the `attribute1=value1` part, then repost if you need help.

Comment: Do all atrribute values start with a "word character" (in the re sense of that dxpression)?

Comment: do you want to replace it with `None` or `'None'` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
import re

s = '[attribute1=value1, attribute2=, attribute3=value3, attribute4=]'
re.sub(r'=(,|])', r'=None\1', s)
```

`\1` is the match in parenthesis.

Comment: You could leverage a character class instead of a plain alternation since the alternatives are single symbols.

Comment: @sehrob beat me to it

Comment: @dimid: Anyway, zemnl is actually looking to learn regex, so it is not a problem :)

Answer (score 0):

With python's `re` module, you can do something like this:

```
# import it first
import re

# your code 
re.sub(r'=([,\]])', '=None\1', your_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
s = '[attribute1=value1, attribute2=, attribute3=value3, attribute4=]'
re.sub(r'=(?!\w)', r'=None', s)
```

This works because the *negative lookahead* `(?!\w)` checks if the `=` character is *not* followed by a 'word' character. The definition of "word character", in regular expressions, is usually something like "a to z, 0 to 9, plus underscore" (case insensitive).

From your example data it seems all attribute values match this. It will not work if the values may start with something like a comma (unlikely), may be quoted, or may start with anything else. If so, you need a more fool proof setup, such as parse from the *start*: skipping the attribute *name* by locating the first `=` character.

Answer (score 0):

Be specific and use a character class:

```
import re

string = "[attribute1=value1, attribute2=, attribute3=value3, attribute4=]"
rx = r'\w+=(?=[,\]])'
string = re.sub(rx, '\g<0>None', string)
print string
# [attribute1=value1, attribute2=None, attribute3=value3, attribute4=None]
```